# How can I reset/remove background colour from a block

Tags: block-editor, editor, visual-editor

So my block has background colour. Let's say it's a paragraph block. I want to remove the background colour completely, but can't find any way in Wordpress' Editor UI.

The only way I found was to switch to code editor view and delete all the code related to the background colour. But I'm sure there must be a no-code way.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely it can be done via custom CSS. But for that we need to check the front end where the background color is there.

Comment: Thanks, made2popular, I am aware I can override everything from my custom css, but I don't want that. I want to know what is the "canonical", ui based way.